# Как использовать android vector drawable с API 16+.

Tags: android, android-drawable, vector-drawable

**Важная правка!**

Долго пытался найти решение, скорее всего неверно ставил вопрос при поиске. Пытался искать по разным комбинациям из этой строки: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_round_done.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070066`

Практически везде предлагали добавить `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` и прочие манипуляции, что я и сделал.

Я совсем не предал значения этой строчке:

`Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector`

Потом попал на англоязычный stackoverflow вопрос [Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48413124/binary-xml-file-line-1-invalid-drawable-tag-vector) в котором пользователь ***abner*** дал совет удалить `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`, за этот ответ его три раза отметили **бесполезным**. Я от безысходности последовал его совету и все заработало!

Но это окончательно меня запутало. Может кто прояснить ситуацию? Почему все советовали добавить `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` и получали очки полезного ответа, но это не помогало. А ответ пользователя ***abner*** с советом удалить эту строчку, набрал три очка бесполезного ответа, но он сработал.

За что отвечает `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` актуальная ли это функция или уже устарела?

---

Если начиная с API 16 это не поддерживается, то с какой минимальной версии API можно спокойно использовать drawable и прочие навороты вроде vector drawable?

Есть **drawable ic_round_done.xml** скачал с https://material.io/tools/icons/ svg файл:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
      android:pathData="M9,16.2l-3.5,-3.5c-0.39,-0.39 -1.01,-0.39 -1.4,0l0,0c-0.39,0.39 -0.39,1.01 0,1.4l4.19,4.19c0.39,0.39 1.02,0.39 1.41,0L20.3,7.7c0.39,-0.39 0.39,-1.01 0,-1.4l0,0c-0.39,-0.39 -1.01,-0.39 -1.4,0L9,16.2z"/>
</vector>
```

Пытался установить **drawable** в **ImageView** разными способами:

```
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_round_done);
```

...

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_round_clear);
```

Постоянно вылетает ошибка:

```
W/ImageView: Unable to find resource: 2131165286
             android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_round_done.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070066
                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2096)
                 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
                 at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:638)
                 at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:367)
                 at com.johndoe.petproject.common.CustomToast.inflateView(CustomToast.java:39)
                 at com.johndoe.petproject.common.CustomToast.error(CustomToast.java:23)
                 at com.johndoe.petproject.ui.activities.TestActivity.add(TestActivity.java:90)
                 at com.johndoe.petproject.ui.activities.TestActivity_ViewBinding$1.doClick(TestActivity_ViewBinding.java:48)
                 at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22)
                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
              Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
                 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
                 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2092)
                 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700) 
                 at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:638) 
                 at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:367) 
                 at com.johndoe.petproject.common.CustomToast.inflateView(CustomToast.java:39) 
                 at com.johndoe.petproject.common.CustomToast.error(CustomToast.java:23) 
                 at com.johndoe.petproject.ui.activities.TestActivity.add(TestActivity.java:90) 
                 at com.johndoe.petproject.ui.activities.TestActivity_ViewBinding$1.doClick(TestActivity_ViewBinding.java:48) 
                 at butterknife.internal.DebouncingOnClickListener.onClick(DebouncingOnClickListener.java:22) 
                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438) 
                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422) 
                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**build.gradle** (**Module: app**):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.johndoe.petproject"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

**build.gradle** (**Project: petproject**)

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Android Sturdio 3.1.4
Build #AI-173.4907809, built on July 24, 2018

Comment: `implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'` Попробуй добавить поддержку векторых изображений

Comment: @McDaggen я кажется пробовал и так, сейчас точно не вспомню, т.к. очень долго не мог решить проблему и что только не пробовал. Я внес правку в вопрос... он стал для меня еще интереснее.